How to write spreadsheet into HTML without the HTML Header in PhpSpreadsheet
Updated code - still generates the HTML Head tag so commented out for now:
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter( $spreadsheet, 'Html' );
                        // $writer->generateStyles( false );
                        //@todo: HTML headers interfering with WP, remove somehow, how?
                        // $writer_output = $writer->save( 'php://output' );


I'm trying to output the spreadsheet into HTML but without styles/header/footer. I just want the table itself. I've done it before but now I can't seem to find the reference online. I basically don't want the generateHTMLHeader() at all. I'm using JS to spit out the HTML that will come from a PHP function/Rest endpoint, I literally just want the spreadsheet content, not the header/footer/styles. Here's what I have so far in the PHP function, this generates the header/footer/styles I don't want:
                        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter( $spreadsheet, 'Html' );
                        // $writer->generateHTMLHeader( false );
                        // $writer->generateStyles( false );
                        $hdr = $writer->generateHTMLHeader();
                        $sty = $writer->generateStyles(false); // do not write <style> and </style>
                        $newstyle = <<<EOF
                        <style type='text/css'>
                        $sty
                        body {
                            background-color: yellow;
                        }
                        </style>
                        EOF;
                        $new_hdr = preg_replace('@</head>@', "$newstyle\n</head>", $hdr);
                        $sheet_data = $writer->generateSheetData();
                        $footer = $writer->generateHTMLFooter();

                        $altogether = $new_hdr . $sheet_data . $footer;

It doesn't seem like you can set generateHTMLHeader/Footer() to false? I've tried removing the hardcoded styles just so the body is empty which is fine and changed the preg_replace('@</head>@', "", $hdr) but that doesn't seem to do anything for the header. There definitely has to be a cleaner way to achieve this. Thank you in advance!
I've checked the official documentation and the code I provided is based on that. I know I've done it last year where I was able to output just the HTML table from the spreadsheet without the HTML header/footer/styles, but that was when PhpSpreadsheet supported PHP7. Not sure if their functions have shifted because they're on PHP8 now. Also tried using $writer->generateSheetData(); alone but that still includes the HTML header/footer.

Why are you doing $altogether = $new_hdr . $sheet_data . $footer if you don't want the header and footer?

@ChrisHaas I was trying to see if I removed the <head> with the $new_hdr but it's all there even with the preg_replace. I realize now the preg_replace is only targetting the closing </head> tag, not the entire thing. Might need a regex to tear the whole thing out...

But I guess I don't know why you are even calling generateHTMLHeader and generateHTMLFooter in the first place?

@ChrisHaas I've added an updated code snippet.
